# Show incremented number on click of a button in an EditText.

Tags: android, android-edittext

when i click on add button it count numbers from 0 and show it one after one but when i click
delete button it clean edit text but when start to click again in add button it count from the last number it stop on it so i want when i click on it in every single time it beginning to count from( 0 ).

```
final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button delet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private int number = 1;


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // random = random();
            edit.setText("" + number++); // i want when i click on it in every single time it beginning to count from( 0 )
                               //because when i delete it and start to click again on add button it count from the last number that stop on it 


        }
    });
    delet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private int numberr;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            edit.setText("0");  // should i change this clean code to make it count from the beginning in every single click ?
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the number varialbe global to make the code functional.

It will always be initialized to 1 as soon as you click on buttons.

```
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


          // make it global or store in intent to retain its value after incrementing and intialize it globally and not here else again will be same case.
//            number = 1;


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // random = random();
                edit.setText("" + number++); // i want when i click on it in every single time it beginning to count from( 0 )
                                   //because when i delete it and start to click again on add button it count from the last number that stop on it 


            }
        });
```

Comment: thank you 4 the replay but can you give me an ex code of this global variable  or intent store ?

Comment: int numbber = -1;//first initialized so that it will not contain any ID. As soon as the button is clicked copy the ID and keep on incrementing it. This varialbe should be at class level.